Help with Floating Shelves
I would like to get a set of 3 white floating shelves, 15.7 in, for my bedroom. The problem is, I'm not sure if I can put floating shelves (or this brand in particular) on shaved popcorn walls? I don't have much experience with this stuff, and it might be a dumb question, but I'm just looking for an answer. Also I'm not sure if I even have shaved popcorn walls. It's bumpy but like smooth.

https://a.co/d/6HwG3FN

Popcorn, shaved popcorn, bumpy, is just a texture on drywall.  Important if trying to match after damage.
You need to find studs behind the drywall to mount the shelves(usually every 16 inches on centre).  There are inexpensive stud sensors that help.
Find the studs, screw the brackets to the studs and mount the shelves.

Do i have to install them with the studs? What if I don't find the studs or I install them without the studs? Would it still work?

@bighatXL   There are drywall anchors that should say the weight they will hold. The problem is drywall is best for holding paint/wall paper and has not much strength in holding weight. The more expensive the weight(stuff you place on the shelves), the less you should trust drywall anchors alone.
